# cannot get the expand button from a tree view to work with selenium and c#

Tags: javascript, c#, css, selenium

i have this part of the code in the website:

```
<td id="tvMain_item_20_expcol" align="center">
  <img src="Images/Tree/tplus.gif" style="display:block;"onclick="ComponentArt_CancelEvent(event);tvMain.ToggleExpand(20,2)" alt="">
  <img src="Images/Tree/tminus.gif" style="display:none;" onclick="ComponentArt_CancelEvent(event);tvMain.ToggleExpand(20,2)" alt="">
```

C#

```
IWebElement expand=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("id('tvMain_item_22_expcol')/x:img[1]"));
expand.Click();
```

I have also tried with

```
//img[@onclick='ComponentArt_CancelEvent(event);tvMain.ToggleExpand(22,2)']
```

I have tried all types of xpath and it isn't working. 
This is part of a tree and according to what I have defined in the xml file he should find the main item I am looking for which is item 22.. 
All that is working fine, but when it comes to clicking on the + to expand he can't.
How can i get selenium with c# to get

Answer (score 0):

Use the following xpath. The first xpath u provided looks invalid and the second one will likely return 2 results and will result in failure

```
//td[@id='tvMain_item_20_expcol']/img[@src='Images/Tree/tplus.gif']
```

Comment: Thanks Sighil, but it doesn't work. I have 39 other elements with the same //img, and now it says cannot click. Is there any other way?

Comment: What exception are u getting?

Comment: I have edited the answer. If this doesnt work you will have to give me more of your HTMLcode